# How to use jquery to perform actions on PHP loop results?

Tags: php, jquery

I've searched and can't seem to make sense of the answers I've found. Grateful for any help!!

**Goal:** Reveal selected message detail in section#details below the listed message headers in section#info.

**Problem:**

1. The following code alerts a result but won't fadeIn();, (or show();, or ...anything).
2. The following code is only grabbing the value of the last result in the PHP while loop.

**php/html/jquery/javascript:**

```
        <section id="info">
            <?php
                $user = $session->username;
                $q = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE UserTo = '%s' ORDER BY SentDate DESC",
                      mysql_real_escape_string($user));
                $getMail = mysql_query($q, $link) or die(mysql_error());

                if(mysql_num_rows($getMail) == 0) {
                    echo "<p>you have no mail</p>";
                }
                else {
                ?>
            <form id="inbox" class="mail">
                <fieldset>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="border: 2px solid purple; width: 100%;">
                            <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; width: 8%; margin-left: 13%;">Status</span>
                            <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; width: 15%;">From</span>
                            <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; width: 45%;">Subject</span>
                            <span style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; width: 16%;">Time</span>
                        </li>
                <?php
                        while($mail = mysql_fetch_object($getMail)) {
                            $status         =       $mail->status;
                            $mailId     =       $mail->mail_id;
                            $from           =       $mail->UserFrom;
                            $subject        =       $mail->Subject;
                            $received       =       $mail->SentDate;
                            $theMessage     =       $mail->Message;
                        ?>
                        <li class="outerDiv" style="border: 2px dotted purple;">
                            <button style="display: inline;" class="viewButton">View</button>
                            <button style="display: inline;">Delete</button>
                            <?php
                            echo "<span style='border: 1px solid red;'>" . $mail_id . "</span>";
                            echo "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 8%; border: 1px solid red;'>" . $status . "</span>";
                            echo "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 15%; border: 1px solid red;'>" . $from . "</span>";
                            echo "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 45%; border: 1px solid red;'>" . $subject . "</span>";
                            echo "<span style='display: inline-block; font-size: x-small; width: 17%; border: 1px solid red;'>" . $received . "</span>";                    
                            ?>
                        </li>
                <?php   }

                    } ?>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="details">
            <div class="theMessage" style="display: none;"><?php echo $theMessage; ?></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".outerDiv").click(function(e) {
                        if($(e.target).is(".viewButton")) {
                    alert($(document).find(".theMessage").text()); //this works
                   $(document).find(".theMessage").text().fadeIn(1000); //this doesn't work

                   var theMessage = $(document).find(".theMessage").text();
                   theMessage.fadeIn(1000); //this doesn't work
                        }
                    });
                    return false; (sometimes prevents default..sometimes not?
                });
            </script>
        </section>
```

p.s. the crazy colors and borders are/were for temp layout purposes. also, the delete button will obviously have functionality... once I can figure this out.

Comment: Separate your PHP and HTML/JS for great success. They exist in two different space/time continua.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some kind of different load time issue going on. So, I can put my JS at the bottom of the page but, don't I need to have the html inside the PHP while loop?

Comment: I mean, narrow down your problem. Take the processed output from PHP and use _that_ as your question input if your HTML/JS is the issue.

Comment: Also please don't write two questions in one in future. :)

Comment: will do. thanks. i'll re-post with different tags for the second issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(document).find(".theMessage").text().fadeIn(1000);
```

use

```
$('.theMessage').fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: To clarify, the important thing here is that you should not attempt to `fade` a text string, but the DOM node itself.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".outerDiv").click(function(e) {
              if($(e.target).is(".viewButton")) {
      $('.theMessage').fadeIn(1000);
              }
          });
          return false;
   });` is that what you mean? tried it.. didn't work. did I do something different than what you meant?

Comment: @tchchn, thats' the way to do it :)

Comment: hmm. ok. thanks for your help. I guess I'll keep playing with it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @tch, Since I see you are pretty new to this community. Make a habit of accepting answers, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Starx is correct, but I figured I'll give an explanation as well.

```
$('.theMessage').fadeIn(1000);
```

In case you don't understand why, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/text/ . The text() method only returns a string, not an actual HTML element that you can manipulate (in this case fadeIn). So text() is good to get or set the contents of an element, but to animate you need to call the methods directly on the $('.theMessage') element.

Comment: ok. here's an interesting thing... I kept my code exactly as I have it above with only one change. I changed the <button> to a <div>... and now it works. weird.